# Refreshable on commit materialized view using MAX()

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, materialized-views, entity-attribute-value

I'm being hit hard by the [entity-attribute-value antipattern](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2009/05/eav-fail.html). Some day, years ago, a guy decided that DDL wasn't sexy, and wanted to develop something "flexible enough" *to keep information about people*. He ignored the fact that people uses to have at least some basic attributes, as name, date of birth, and the like. Not only that, he put a bunch of (side-effects-ridden) PL/SQL packages on top of that schema. The thing managed to be a key subsystem in which other applications relied on.

Fast forward some years and 20 million rows. The guy isn't at the company anymore, and I have to deal with this. I need to implement some basic searches that right now would require multiple inner joins and just take forever for some cases. Rewriting the whole thing it's not possible, so I want to "pivot" the most important attributes.

I thought that materialized views could be a viable alternative, but I need some guidance, since I have never used them. I would like to get a table like this:

```
  select
      uid,
       max(case when att = 'NAME' then UPPER(value) end) name,
       max(case when att = 'SURNAME' then UPPER(value) end) surname,
       max(case when att = 'BIRTH' then DATEORNULL(value) end) birth,
     ....,
     count(*) cnt
 from t
 group by uid
```

as I understand reading  Oracle docs, I should be able to create a "REFRESHABLE ON COMMIT" materialized view with MAX() [if the query has no where clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/basicmv.htm).

But can't get it to work. I've tried:

```
create materialized view log on t WITH SEQUENCE,ROWID,(value) INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

create materialized view t_view
 refresh fast on commit
 as
  select
      uid,
       max(case when att = 'NAME' then UPPER(value) end) name,
       max(case when att = 'SURNAME' then UPPER(value) end) surname,
       max(case when att = 'BIRTH' then DATEORNULL(value) end) birth,
     count(*) cnt
 from t
 group by uid
```

It works for inserts, but not for updates. I see that is capable of these things:

```
  REFRESH_COMPLETE                                                             

  REFRESH_FAST                                                                 

  REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT
```

but I think I should see also REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML. Any ideas?

Update: Output of dbms_mview.explain_mview

```
REFRESH_COMPLETE             |Y|
REFRESH_FAST                 |Y|
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT    |Y|
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML|N|mv uses the MIN or MAX aggregate functions
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ANY_DML   |N|see the reason why REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML is disabled
REFRESH_FAST_PCT             |N|PCT is not possible on any of the detail tables in the mater
```

Comment: after you run `EXECUTE DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_MVIEW ('T_VIEW');`, what's the output of `SELECT capability_name,  possible, SUBSTR(related_text,1,8)
  AS rel_text, SUBSTR(msgtxt,1,60) AS msgtxt
FROM MV_CAPABILITIES_TABLE
ORDER BY seq;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MV_CAPABILITIES_TABLE.MSGTXT` is wrong, what you really need to do is replace `case` with `decode`.

When I tried this on 11g I got the message `CASE expressions present in materialized view`.  Changing it to use `decode` fixed it on both 10g and 11g.